# Java While Loop breaking with a negative

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am having a problem with this java project I am working on for tomorrow. I am supposed to make a while loop that prompts the user for the prices of items and end the loop with any negative number, that negative number cannot be counted. Then I have to prompt the user for their membership discount level plat 15% off/gold 7%/silver 3%/non member 0% off using variables 3,2,1,0 respectively. For invalid input of status of membership, the user needs to enter again with a valid one using a do-while loop. Then I use the appropriate discount % off the sum of the items then tax it. The last few steps are simple enough, but I am stuck at the loops.

I did some searching and found this block of code on this site that does the job for the first while loop but does not end in the way I need it to.
[Using While Loop instead of a For Loop in Java to ask User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513692/using-while-loop-instead-of-a-for-loop-in-java-to-ask-user-input)

I modified it to fit my needs but I still cannot find a way to make the throwable = to any negative number ie <0. Is that even possible? I am pretty sure there is a way to do this much simpler without try/catch which I have not learned yet. Here is my very slightly modified version

```
Scanner askPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
BigDecimal totalPrice = new BigDecimal("0");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter item price or negative number to quit:") ;
    try {
        double price = askPrice.nextDouble();
        totalPrice = totalPrice.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(price)));
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(totalPrice.toString());
}
```

I tried turning the try and catch statements into if / else and replacing the catch throwable with else(askPrice <0), but I was getting tons of errors.

I greatly appreciate any help that can be offered.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a way without try/catch. `break` will remove yourself from the `while` loop, so you are correct there. Try doing a simple `if` statement that checks the value of `price`, and if you need to `break` or not.

Comment: Don't use try/catch -- totally unnecessary.  `if (price < 0.0) break;` is all you need.

Comment: Another thing to say, don't catch `Throwable`, instead your specific `Exception`, and you should always handle it e.g. printing the stacktrace to know what caused the error.

Comment: Thanks, all of the answers have been very helpful I wish I could checkmark everyone.

Comment: `askPrice` is a `Scanner`! you cannot compare it like `else(askPrice <0)`! You have to compare it like `price < 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like homework. I know a lot of teachers are against students using 'break' to exit a loop. Here is how I would do it. A try-catch statement is unnecessary.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double input = 0.0;
    double totalPrice = 0.0;

    do {
        totalPrice += input;
        input = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    while(input >= 0);
}
```

Using a while loop:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double totalPrice = 0.0;
    double input = keyboard.nextDouble();

    while(input >= 0) {
    totalPrice += input;
    input = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. All of the try/catch and strings were confusing to me, dumbing it down to simple doubles and loops was great. How would you convert your do while into just a while?

Comment: I updated the answer to include a while loop version. I would suggest that you use a do while. It's simpler.

Comment: Thanks for adding the while version, I appreciate it. This is my first programming class and its easy to get lost for me.

Comment: I know what it's like. I'm a programming student too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple do while loop that you are looking for

```
double price = 0;
do {
    try {
        price = askPrice.nextDouble();
        // if the price was  > 0 we need to add it to the total
        if(price > 0)
            totalPrice = totalPrice.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(price)));  
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        // exit our loop, if the user entered an invalid double. Maybe you want to display a message instead?
        price = -1; 
    }
} while(price >= 0);
```

The key is a do-while loop vs a while loop. The do-while loop will always run one time prior to analysing the loop condition. This allows you to accept the users input inside the loop and keep your code clean. I belive it is good practice to avoid using the `break` statement when possible. It will generally keep you from writing bad code (with the exception of switch statements of course).

**Edit:** For the record I think the try catch statement is not only necessary but mandatory for any user input. When a user enters an invalid number do you want a nasty error with a stack trace being thrown or your program to gracefully handle the bad input and notify the user. Most important it gets new programmers thinking about error handling, a very important part of software development.

Answer (score 1):

Try/catch is for handling exceptions and totally unnecessary here.

```
    Scanner askPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigDecimal totalPrice = new BigDecimal("0");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Enter item price or negative number to quit:") ;
        double price = askPrice.nextDouble(); 
        if (price<0)
            break;
        else {
            totalPrice = totalPrice.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(price)));       
        }
        System.out.println(totalPrice.toString());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't you check for negative number.

And you need to move your last System.out outside the loop

```
    Scanner askPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigDecimal totalPrice = new BigDecimal("0");

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Enter item price or negative number to quit:");
        try {
            double price = askPrice.nextDouble();
            if (price < 0)
                break;

            totalPrice = totalPrice.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(price)));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(totalPrice.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of understand, but if you want exit with a negative number as input, use this:

```
    Scanner askPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigDecimal totalPrice = new BigDecimal("0");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double price = 0.0d;
    try {
        while (0.0d <= price) {
         System.out.println("Enter item price or negative number to quit:") ;
         price = askPrice.nextDouble();        
         totalPrice = totalPrice.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(price)));       
        }
     }catch (Throwable t) {           
        System.err.println(t.getMessage());         
     }
     System.out.println(totalPrice.toString());
```

Some points:

- try/catch always out of a cycle, beacuase the code is more readable and faster
- inside catch, you have to put a syserr, not sysout
- in the orginal code, the eternal lopp finish when the user put a dollar char, what throw an Exception in converting as number with instruction

  askPrice.nextDouble()

In your case, the instructions

```
 double price = askPrice.nextDouble();        
 totalPrice = totalPrice.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(price)));
```

don't throw any exception with negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is better to write your own code instead of copying code for simple examples. That way you will learn a lot. In the code you have a missing closing brace for `while` loop, I hope there is a brace closing later.

You can temporarily fix the code by throwing an exception after getting the price:

```
double price = askPrice.nextDouble();
if(price < 0) throw new ArithmeticException("Negative Price!");
```

I am not sure whether that is what you want.